# jQuery $.ajax call works in Chrome, but not any other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

The following call works perfectly in Chrome, but fails in every other browser.

```
function getInfo(r,c,f){
  return $.parseJSON($.ajax({
      url: baseURL + 'somethingAPI/getInfo',
      data: {
        "data_r": r,
        "data_c": c,
        "data_f": f
      },
      //success: function(data){},
      dataType: "json",
      async: FALSE
    }).response);
}
```

Yes, I'm using a synchronous ajax call and I believe it is necessary as I don't want any of the other JS to run without this executing and returning data. Although, I'm not entirely sure if something else should be happening with the success callback.

Anyway, in Chrome I get the response object (JSON) and can access the data within just fine.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you using the `console` object anywhere, like `console.log` or something?

Comment: @Anurag not using console at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your point about not knowing how to avoid `async: false`, is this something like what you're looking to accomplish?

```
function getInfo(r, c, f, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: baseURL + 'somethingAPI/getInfo',
    data: {
      "data_r": r,
      "data_c": c,
      "data_f": f
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: callback,
  });
}

getInfo('foo', 'bar', 'baz', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was trying to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than parsingJson on the ajax query, here's the syntax I use to conquer these challenges

```
    $.ajax({
       url: "pagegoeshere.php",                   
       timeout: 30000,
       type: "POST",
       data: 'data1='+data1+'&data2='+data2,
       dataType: 'json',
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)  {
         alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
       },
       success: function(returnjson){                                                                                                   
           var returnstuff = returnjson.returnstuff;
           //Do next Javascript step here
       }
});
```

You can run ensuing javascript/jquery in the success and "stack" events together on success of your Ajax call.  That way, if it works, it proceeds.  Otherwise, the error handling can occur in the provided error section in a manner that you define.  I generally fire my ajax calls on a click handler, but it's certainly doable to run it in a function as you have chosen.  Be sure to check your return JSON (could be mailed from your processing page, for example) to make sure it's valid JSON.  [Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) is your friend!

I've had chrome effectively parse bad HTML and JSON while the other browsers don't on several occasions.  I'd suspect it's something along those lines that's specifically causing your issues.